# Angular Ui-grid - export to excel ui-grid error

Tags: angular-ui-grid

good, i am using this code to link http://brianhann.com/exporting-spreadsheets-from-ui-grid/ export to excel ui-grid from a table, but I skip this mistake, I pass what happens to me.
I error occurs in the code where it says:

```
$rows.forEach(function (row, ri) {
  ri +=1;
  $scope.gridApi.grid.columns.forEach(function (col, ci) {
    var loc = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({r: ri, c: ci});
    sheet[loc] = {
      v: row[ci].value,
      t: 's'
    };
    endLoc = loc;
  });
```

Regards, and thank you very much.

The code of controller is:

```
$scope.exportXLSX = function(){
var data = [
  [] // header row
];

var rows = uiGridExporterService.getData($scope.gridApi.grid, uiGridExporterConstants.VISIBLE, uiGridExporterConstants.VISIBLE);

var sheet = {};

$scope.gridApi.grid.columns.forEach(function (col, i) {
  if (col.visible) {
    var loc = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({r: 0, c: i})
    sheet[loc] = {
      v: col.displayName
    };
  }
});

var endLoc;
rows.forEach(function (row, ri) {
  ri +=1;
  $scope.gridApi.grid.columns.forEach(function (col, ci) {
    var loc = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({r: ri, c: ci});
    sheet[loc] = {
      v: row[ci].value,
      t: 's'
    };
    endLoc = loc;
  });
});
sheet['!ref'] = XLSX.utils.encode_range({ s: 'A1', e: endLoc });

var workbook = {
  SheetNames: ['Sheet1'],
  Sheets: {
    Sheet1: sheet
  }
};

var wopts = { bookType: 'xlsx', bookSST: false, type: 'binary' };
var wbout = XLSX.write(workbook, wopts);

saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], {type: ""}), "test.xlsx");
```

};

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a30m2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you using alasql

https://github.com/agershun/alasql

With a code like that:

```
    $scope.exportMyData = function() {

        alasql('SELECT c1 AS columnA, c2 AS columnB, c3 AS columnC INTO XLSX("data.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ?',
          [$scope.myDataSource]);
    }
```

And in the HTML

```
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="exportMyData()"> Export </button>
```